# How to enable OpenGL rendering on Fedora 18 with an Intel Corporation 82852/855GM?

Tags: fedora, graphics, opengl

On an older laptop that runs Fedora 18, and has a Intel Corporation 82852/855GM Integrated Graphics Device, I cannot get OpenGL to run on it.

In fact, I have no 3D acceleration whatsoever.

I have the correct drivers installed, but I can't get OpenGL to work.

`glxinfo` reports:

```
name of display: :0.0
X Error of failed request:  BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Serial number of failed request:  22
  Current serial number in output stream:  25
```

In fact no GLX application will start, all stop with the same error message.

Do I have to enable it in the Kernel or put something into xorg.conf?

As it has been requested, [here's my `xorg.0.log`](http://pastie.org/5931677), and [the ouptut of `lspci`](http://pastie.org/5958056).

Comment: (1) In "theory", X11 is very intelligent now that it will start correctly without xorg.conf. As that chip is supported by `xserver-xorg-video-intel`, X11 should be able to load it correctly. You can try moving the xorg.conf away(rename it) and start restart X11 to see if it does the trick. (2) If the above does not help, post `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

Comment: I've uploaded and linked the xorg.0.log file. Moving xorg.conf didn't help...

Comment: Strange, base on your Xorg.0.log, drive and glx loaded. Line70 GLX loaded
Line154 identify chipset correctly
Line197 DRI2 loaded
Line229 AIGLX initialized. How much memory the video card has? Post your xorg.conf also.

Comment: Well, there is no xorg.conf as such. There's just a file inside `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-anaconda-keyboard.conf`, which does no settings to the driver part of things...

Comment: hmm, seems my answer is actually useless, the current intel driver actaully only use uxa. So there is no point(and no use) to add that section.

Comment: @JohnSiu Yeah, I tried anyway: Same symptoms.

Comment: Please add output of `lspci` into question.

Comment: @JohnSiu OK, I've just added that. Although I don't see how this is gonna help much, as I said in my question what kind of graphics chip I have...

Comment: There have been several updates to the mesa packaged since I've posted this question, but it still doesn't work. Has anyone some newer information by now?

Comment: Fedora 18 is at end-of-life, upgrade. There isn't any support. If it persists with a currently supported Fedora, I suspect you'd have more luck on Fedora-specific fora (or its Bugzilla).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem sorted itself. There was an update of Mesa a couple of weeks ago, and it now works beautifully.

Just thought I'd share! :3

Answer (score 1):

You may be hit by a recent mesa 9.x bug/issue [[link here]](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1071530).

To check if you are using mesa 9.x

```
yum list installed | grep mesa
```

If you have `mesa-9.0-3.fc18`, try downgrade to `mesa-8.1-0.19.fc18`.

```
yum downgrade mesa
```

Comment: I found that one myself as well, but I didn't bother downgrading just yet. (Linux Mint Debian Edition was unaffected so I figured it's Ubuntu only) I'll do it just as I find some spare time.

Comment: Linux Mint still using Mesa 8.x. Fedora 18 upgraded repository last month, that's why you get hit. Fedora is very cutting edge in terms of pacakage upgrade :)

Comment: I just tried, bit of a problem, though: I can only downgrade to `mesa-dri-drivers-9.0.1-1.fc18.i686`. I tried downgrading further, but older packaged are simply not available. At least not from repos, that is.

Comment: You properly have to download mesa-8.1-0.19.fc18 rpm directly. But all link I search from google seems dead, this is just strange.

Comment: That's why I was asking to begin with. It seems the bug kinda sits there, but since the hardware is so old, not many people bother fixing it...

Comment: Well, it seems weird to me, mesa-8 for fc18 was there last Aug something, how can the package completely disappeared from the Internet. At least there should be rpm packages somewhere.

Comment: No matter where I look, I seem to be unable to find the mesa-8 packages. I guess the only thing I can do at this point, is wait for a fix to be pushed through... Mesa 9.0.2 is on its way, Fedora is usually quite quick in getting this kinda thing done. Let's hope for the best...

Comment: Or use fc17 mesa.

Comment: Do you have access to mesa-9.1-2? Someone say it "kind of" fix the issue.

Comment: I cannot conclude that I was hit by the bug. According to the bug tracker, the bug still exists, but in the mean time, the problem sorted itself out. Was probably some other, minor bug, they fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no OpenGL hardware support for your card. Try "i915 modeset=1"  as an addition to your boot line.

Comment: Well, there used to be one then, as it worked with Linux Mint just a few days ago...

Comment: According to [this link](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Intel), 855GM support OpenGL 1.3.